# /etc/fstab: meaning of "nofail" if "noauto" is already specified

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, automounting, systemd-mount

From my understanding of `/etc/systemd` options, `noauto` means that the device will not be mounted at boot time (or with `mount -a`).

Is there *any* situation where adding `nofail` changes the behaviour if `noauto` is already given, or is it totally redundant?

`man` [`systemd.mount(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) says:

> With `noauto`, this mount will not be added as a dependency for local-fs.target or remote-fs.target. This means that it will not be mounted automatically during boot, unless it is pulled in by some other unit.
>
> With `nofail`, this mount will be only wanted, not required, by local-fs.target or remote-fs.target. This means that the boot will continue even if this mount point is not mounted successfully.

What about automount situations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just for the record:

For an external USB disk which is usually not connected at startup, I have an fstab entry

```
/dev/disk/by-label/data /data   xfs noauto,user,noatime 0   0
```

When booting there is no error as `noauto`keeps the system from trying to mount. When I try to mount manually without the drive connected, I immediately get the error

```
~$ mount /data
mount: special device /dev/disk/by-label/data does not exist
~$
```

If I change the line in fstab to

```
/dev/disk/by-label/data /data   xfs noauto,nofail,user,noatime  0   0
```

there is no error reported, even when the drive is not available:

```
~$ mount /data
~$
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd.

Answer (score 6):

`noauto` will still return an error (stderr) during boot if the source is not available.

`nofail` will remove the errorcheck.

`nofail` without a `x-systemd.device-timeout=` specified will default to a 90 second timeout though when the source is not available and you or a process attempt to mount it manually.

Note:`x-systemd.device-timeout=0` sets infinite timeout.

Edit: Citation

> `nofail` Do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: That's not correct. If 'noauto' is set, the `mount -a` issued at startup will not try to mount and therefore there will be no waiting for the device. If you specify `noauto`, and try to mount the drive later on manually, you will get an error if it is not available. With `nofail` there will be no error message, even when the device is not available. What do you mean with 'automount situations'?

Comment: Since you ask here: I could see that one way the line would get "executed without  `mount -a`, is with autofs and `cd /mnt/autofs-directory`.  I'm wondering if nofail has any effect in that case.

Comment: @m_krsic Welcome to SE.unix. It's good practice to provide evidence (links) for your assertions on SE sites. I've been shocked at how many times I self-corrected in posting what I thought was the case when I got chapter-and-verse in providing a reference.

Comment: @ridgy What isn't correct? If `noauto`  is is set `mount -a` issued at startup will not try to mount it, but a check is performed to see if the source is there.

Comment: @m_krsic Have you tried this personally, or do you have a reference? Why would it bother checking something that it's not going to mount anyway?